Teen space Sci-Fi book/series that was turned into cartoon, copyright issues with Star Trek
My co-worker is looking for a book/series from probably the 70's or 80's that was turned into a cartoon in the 80's or 90's but both the book and the cartoon ran into copyright issues with Star Trek and the cartoon was taken off the air after 1 season.   It had Christian themes in it, and they visited various planets, with a teen crush throughout.  Any one have a clue?
